# How to do colsum and average on the same dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to add a new row to this dataframe below name total. Now for the columns  `counts`,`cost`,`views` are colsums or totals but for `average`  I want to do average and for average I want to do a custom formula .So how can I do that. I did use the `janitor` library (`adorn_totals("row")`)but it just does the sum . Below is the sample dataframe:

```
data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                Site = c("Channel1", "Channel2", "Channel3", "Channel4"),
         Counts = c(7637587, 19042385, 72019057, 45742745),
                Cost = c(199999.993061, 102196.9726, 102574.79, 196174.712132),
    Views = c(3007915, 5897235, 14245859, 24727451),
   Average = c(2.54, 3.23, 5.05543800482653, 2.21111111111111),
               avg_views = c(7.5197875, 14.7430875, 35.6146475, 48.24)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can help you but that's what I'm using when I want to add a **Total** row at the end. I also use this with the `data.table` package.

**Code example:**

```
dt <- rbind(dt, data.table(Site = "Total",
                           Counts = sum(dt[, Counts]),
                           Cost = sum(dt[, Cost]),
                           Views = mean(dt[, Views]),
                           Average = sum(dt[, Average]),
                           avg_views = paste("Hi OP")))
```

**Output :**

```
      Site    Counts     Cost    Views   Average  avg_views
1: Channel1   7637587 200000.0  3007915  2.540000   7.519787
2: Channel2  19042385 102197.0  5897235  3.230000  14.743087
3: Channel3  72019057 102574.8 14245859  5.055438  35.614647
4: Channel4  45742745 196174.7 24727451  2.211111  48.240000
5:    Total 144441774 600946.5 11969615 13.036549  Hi OP
```

You can apply whatever functions you want. In my code example you have `sum()` and also `mean()` but you could use anything.

Comment: I did use `data.table` but still get this error `Error in `[.data.frame`(dt, , Counts) : object 'Counts' not found
`

Comment: Simply add ``data.table()`` instead of ``data.frame()`` in your sample data, it works just fine for me. You can also convert your data by doing ``as.data.table(dt)``.

Comment: @SNT Glad I could help! Also note that this method works really well but is less usefull when you have a lot of columns since you need to manually enter each functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base way. It's ok.

```
DF_summary <- colSums(DF[, -1])
DF_summary[4] <- mean(DF[, 5])
rbind(DF, c('Total',DF_summary))

      Site    Counts          Cost    Views          Average   avg_views
1 Channel1   7637587 199999.993061  3007915             2.54   7.5197875
2 Channel2  19042385   102196.9726  5897235             3.23  14.7430875
3 Channel3  72019057     102574.79 14245859 5.05543800482653  35.6146475
4 Channel4  45742745 196174.712132 24727451 2.21111111111111       48.24
5    Total 144441774 600946.467793 47878460 3.25913727898441 106.1175225
```